# .NET set variable to running process (if process is running)

Tags: c#, .net, phantomjs

I am running `Phantomjs.exe`  in the background. 
I would like to keep this process running all the time. When it's time to use this process (on button click) I would like to check if the process is running. If it is running I would like to use that process. If it is not running, I will start a new process.

I've found out how to check if the process is running and how to start a new process in that case. But I don't know how to connect C# variable with already running process? (so there is no need to start - stop process each time, which takes a lot of time)

My code:

```
public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
{
  foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
  {
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(name))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
        PhantomJSDriver driver = null;
        bool phantomOpened = IsProcessOpen("Phantomjs");

      if(!phantomOpened)
     {
        PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
      }
      else //set PhantomJSDriver to running exe
     {
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some misconceptions here:

- Checking for a process with a given name cannot ensure you're detecting the right process. I can rename Notepad to PhantomJS and you'll detect the wrong one.
- You can't simply access another process's memory. Each process has its own virtual memory that is protected from other processes.

Solutions are:

- for detecting a running process, use a named Mutant (Mutex). If you find it, the process is running, if not, start the process. Give it a GUID or other name that can hardly be guessed or reused.
- for exchanging data between two processes use a [named pipe or shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9701757/480982) (general concepts, language independent) or an [IPC channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) (.NET specific)

Make yourself failiar with those concepts and you'll probably find code examples here on SO.

Alternate solutions I would not recommend:

- Sending a Window message to the other process might not work reliably in case multiple desktops are used.
- Implementing a debugger that attaches to the process and ... well, do difficult stuff.

Comment: Is there really no other (easier) way? Let's say if I create a simple exe with only one method and then run it. The only thing I want is to call that simple method from another application. Do I really have to use IPC / named pipes for this?

Comment: @FrenkyB: if it's that simple, why not implement the method in your code directly? Or load the EXE as an assembly into your application and call the method there...